How to make MacOS terminal to emit a warning from a SSH session
I run some lengthy scripts over SSH, using the default MacOS terminal application. Usually, I leave this terminal running and change virtual desktops, only to forget I left this running.
I would like to have some sort of warning (sound, pop-up, bouncing icon, anything, really) for when the script finishes or dies because of an error.
The issue I am facing is that, because I'm SSHing to another computer, any command I can issue from the script itself will essencially run on the host machine.
Is there a way to have MY terminal to emit some sort of signal?

What's the return code for a failed SSH session in this case? (You should be able to see with echo $?, but you'll need to run that before any other CLI commands.)

Save following script in test.osa,
on run(argv)
tell application "Terminal"
    activate -- Switching to the desktop fo the Terminal
    set frontmost of  first window whose (visible is true) and (tty of tab 1 contains item 1 of argv) to true
end tell
end run

then on your ssh command :
ssh ... ; osascript test.osa $(tty)

when ssh finishes, the Terminal will come to the foreground.

Thanks. In this case, I would need to terminate the ssh session from my script. It could work, I'll give it a try.

If the SSH session ends in an error (non-zero return code) then you can use a double pipe (||) to notify you somehow. For example,:
ssh user@host || say "SSH session crashed"
If the session ends cleanly (with a zero return code), then nothing will happen, but if the session doesn't end cleanly then a voice will say "SSH session crashed".

Interesting, thanks. I didn't know of the || usage. I guess I can terminate the session from my script and just pass an error code to it.
